# How to capture the index of points before instantiating objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to capture the index of points before objects are instantiated?

Comment: Hello ! Have you tried the [index node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/input_index.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the index of points (on the point domain) before instantiating objects on them, or you can capture the index of instances before realizing them (on the instance domain).

Like this:
[image]

Or this:
[image]